# How to use i18n on an android app with nativescript and vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I'm actually working on an nativescript mobile app with vuejs (android app).
I would like use an i18n module in my app but I don't find any Nativescript and Vuejs tutorial to do it.
I have already try some similar tutorials but without success...
Anyone have a tutorial for this issue or some advices to help me ? Or explain me why my request isn't consistent.
Thx for advance !

Comment: If you have tried using i18n the way it is described for Vue.js apps in plugin documentation, please include code samples of such attempt and issues you have encountered.

Comment: This type of advice requests are more welcomed in the #vue channel of NativeScript community slack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [vue-i18next](https://github.com/panter/vue-i18next) is more Vue way of doing it on Web, if you prefer a native mobile solution, you might be interested in [nativescript-localize](https://github.com/lfabreges/nativescript-localize#vue) plugin.

**JS**

```
import { localize } from "nativescript-localize";

Vue.filter("L", localize);
```

**Tempalte**

```
<Label :text="'Hello world !'|L"></Label>
<Label :text="'I am %s'|L('user name')"></Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing specific about using an i18n package with NativeScript-Vue. For instance, I am using [vue-i18next](https://github.com/panter/vue-i18next) in my NativeScript-Vue project.